# $.get can't pass the data to the php file

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

When I used `page=1` ,everything is OK.BUT if I changed

```
$.get("getajax.php","page=1" ,function(data){ }
```

to

```
$.get("getajax.php","page="+pageno ,function(data){ }
```

then the program return a false and "fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object", I think this means the $result has problems.Thus , the $query has a problem?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="showdata"></div>  

<input type="hidden" id="currentresult" value="1" />
<button id="show">Load</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).on('click','#show',function(e){

            var pageno = $('#currentresult').val(); 
            $.get("getajax.php","page="+pageno ,function(data){ 

                pageno++;
                $('#currentresult').val(pageno); 
                $('#showdata').append(data);                                                 

            });
        });
    });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And the getajax.php

```
<!-- This is ajax data. -->
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "maroon5");
$page=isset($_GET["page"])?$_GET["page"]:0;
$pageNo = $page;

$startLimit = ($pageNo-1)*2;

$query = "SELECT * from tour LIMIT $startLimit,2 ";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query); 
var_dump($result);


while($row = $result -> fetch_assoc()){

?>
<div>
    <h4>
    month:<?php echo $row["month"]; ?>day:<?php echo $row["day"]; ?>           
    </h4>
</div>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: What is (0-1)*2 ???? and does `LIMIT -2,2` work well for you?

Comment: Or does it generate the error `ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-2,2'` link it does for me

Comment: And therefore `$result = mysqli_query($con,$query); ` will return FALSE

Comment: And therefore `$result -> fetch_assoc()` will cause the error that you say you are getting

Comment: $.get("getajax.php","page:"+pageno ,function(data){ }

Comment: @ashanrupasinghe that's not right at all...

Comment: What are you trying to do with `$startLimit = ($pageNo-1)*2;`? You already have the page number.

Comment: $.get( "getajax.php", { 'page':pageno },function(data){ } );

Comment: @Erevald ,I use $startLimt as the data index so that I can query two data every time.

Comment: before execute the sql query can you check what is the value of the $page variable in $page=isset($_GET["page"])?$_GET["page"]:0;

if $page variable contain correct value, 
try $page= (int)$page; instead of using $page variable directly

Comment: @RiggsFolly ,I know what you mean ,but I set the  `var pageno = $('#currentresult').val()` , it is not "pageno = 1" at first?so first time,the $startLimit = (1-1)*2, the query will search from index 0.

Comment: @ashanrupasinghe ,Yeah ,I've checked $page before $page=isset($_GET["page"])?$_GET["page"]:0;  ,the value is 0. But how did this happen, the $.get didn't pass the data to php?

Comment: @LTulip, change `pageno++;` to `pageno+=2` and in php put `$page` straight to your sql query. No need to add offset value with `$startLimit`.

Comment: did not you try $.get( "getajax.php", { "page":pageno },function(data){ } );
I think this is the correct way.

also in function(data){ 

                pageno++;
                $('#currentresult').val(pageno); 
                $('#showdata').append(data);                                                 

            });

here you can check  pageno using a alert method,
I am sure the function not identify the variable

Comment: @ashanrupasinghe ,yes I tried this ,it didn't work , I add `echo $page` before $query, the browser tells $page is 0. Does this mean the php can not get $page from $.get?

Comment: no,
I think the callback function dose not identify the 'pageno' variable and not work 'pageno++', have you checked that

Comment: @ashanrupasinghe ,I use this $.get( "getajax.php", { "page":pageno },function(data){ } );  after I close the brower and open it again, the program is right and data is correct, I guess it is the $.get cache ,because I just have 10 data in mysql table, after the input value = 5（every time I query 2data）,there is no more data in the table.Only I close the brower the value can count from 1. Thank you for your help:)

Answer (score 0):

The reason why `$.get("getajax.php","page=1" ,function(data){` works is because it always sends 1 to your php, thus creating the sql query of `SELECT * from tour LIMIT 0,2`

However if you were to change to `$.get("getajax.php","page="+pageno ,function(data){`, page will get assigned `pageno` which increases dynamically every time the button is clicked thus creating different queries to the DB like:

```
first click:  "SELECT * from tour LIMIT 0,2"
second click: "SELECT * from tour LIMIT 2,2"
third click:  "SELECT * from tour LIMIT 4,2"
```

As you can see the second, or third click would be different. Not completely sure but this is most likely your case. One of these queries is not finding any results, thus throwing the error at `fetch_assoc()`

Comment: Yeah ,I know what you mean , I use ` $.get( "getajax.php", { "page":pageno },function(data){ } );` instead of `$.get("getajax.php","page="+pageno ,function(data){ })`,then it works. And the problem is $.get will cache the value unless close the browser and open it again,the value would count from 1. Fresh the window is no use.

Comment: i never heard of `$.get` caching the values. Something else must be going on there. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try mysqli_error function to get real error

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query)or die (mysqli_error($con));
```

Answer (score 0):

If your page if `0` then `startLimit` would be `-2`

Add a bit of logic here

```
$startLimit = ($pageNo-1)*2;

if($startLimit < 0)
{
    $startLimit = 0;
}
```

Should work! Though not the perfect solution but would work